# Using a WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I built a WCF Data Service by following a blog.

It works ok, but I don't get the expected result format in the browser.

When I run the project, I get this:

[image]

But, when I try to browse one of these tables, say Customers, this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the Customers are there, but all I see is the current date for each one of them.

There must be something I'm not doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like firefox is displaying the data as an RSS Feed because your service returns an xml payload. There should be a setting in Firefox to turn it off... I think it is under firefox > options > applications > web feed.

Comment: I ended up using Chrome because Internet Explorer has a douwnload limit. I wasn't able to turn web feed off in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Since the response is ATOM-based, Firefox will assume this is an RSS feed and try to apply the RSS view (and fail, as you can see).

I tend to use IE when working with OData (and disable "Feed Reading view" under Options -> Content). In Firefox you can change some settings under Options -> Applications -> Web Feed, but I haven't figured out yet how to completely disable it.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said, this is the default RSS view, correctly rendered in Firefox.  You can still use the View Page Source option in Firefox to view the actual XML returned by your server.

If you want your data to render in a more user-friendly manner in the default RSS view you will have to use OData's feed customisation features, for example, to set a value for the Atom title field.